# MySql - Trouble Creating View

Tags: mysql, view

Receiving this message when trying to create a view in MySql.  I've tried giving an alias to each column as well and still receive an error.  Wha Happon!? Thanks in advance.

**Error Message**

> ERROR 1060: Duplicate column name 'ID'

**Code**

```
CREATE VIEW contactnotes AS
SELECT contact.ID, log.ID, contact.Name, log.notes
FROM log 
JOIN contact 
ON log.ID = contact.ID
```

**Alias Attempt**

```
CREATE VIEW contactnotes AS
SELECT contact.ID as id1, log.ID as id2, contact.Name, log.notes
FROM log 
JOIN contact 
ON id1 = id2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW contactnotes AS
SELECT contact.ID as id1, log.ID as id2, contact.Name, log.notes
FROM log 
JOIN contact 
ON log.ID = contact.ID
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW contactnotes AS
SELECT contact.ID as id1, log.ID as id2, contact.Name, log.notes
FROM log 
INNER JOIN contact USING (ID)
```